# Pro Guard for a basic application : android

Tags: android, google-play, proguard, publishing

I have made my first application for android. It does nothing much just stores some user specified data in SQLiteDatabase and manages it. Now, the app requires no special permission. And while reading the guidelines for publishing it, I came across Pro-Guard. On researching it and reading the developer page on it, I am not able to understand that do I also for a basic app need to set up this pro guard file. I already have a proguard-project.txt in my application folder. It does not have a code, but normal English sentences. What should I do ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In the **project.properties** file you can enable **Proguard** by uncommenting the line that says **proguard.config=${sdk.dir}/tools/proguard/proguard-android.txt:proguard-project.txt**.

**Note:**

When you build your application in release mode, either by running **ant release** or by using the **Export Wizard** in Eclipse, the build system automatically checks to see if the **proguard.config** property is set. If it is, **ProGuard** automatically processes the application's bytecode before packaging everything into an .apk file. Building in debug mode does not invoke ProGuard, because it makes debugging more cumbersome.

[This](http://developer.android.com/tools/help/proguard.html) is the documentation.

Comment: Thanks sir, what all will it do ?

Comment: After enabling the proguard,when ever you export your apk,proguard will do its job automatically

Comment: Sir, can you please specify some tasks. I most importantly want to know that, the key with which I signed the application in eclipse will be safe.

Comment: again, thanks but for my app I just need to uncomment that, right ?

Comment: yaa,,just uncomment it..thats enough.

Comment: Sir, after un commenting its coming "'proguard' is not correctly spelled", also everthing in proguard-project.txt everything starts with #

Comment: dont uncomment anything in project.txt. just uncomment the line in project.properties .thats enough.

Comment: but there is an error -> 'proguard' is not correctly spelled

Comment: Your project.properties  may be invalid.just create a new project and try the same.if it works successfully then compare it with this.It may help.